# How to represent $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\zeta(2k)}{\pi^k}\right)^3 $ as a sum over $\cot$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

From the Taylor series of $\cot(z)$, one has $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(2k)}{\pi^k} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{\pi} }{2} \cot(\sqrt{\pi}) \approx 0.6811769103 $$
and summing the $\cot(z)$ series over $\frac{1}{n}$ yields
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\zeta(2k)}{\pi^k}\right)^2 = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\cot \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{2n}\right)\approx 0.2873762006 $$
So my question is: *Is there a general equivalent sum that consists of $\cot(z)$ for the sum below?* If that is too difficult, how would one represent $s=3$ as a sum over $\cot(z)$ ?
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\zeta(2k)}{\pi^k}\right)^s $$
Edit: $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\zeta(2k)}{\pi^k}\right)^3 $ converges to about $ 0.1449028093 $